# How to open a url link from qweb?

Tags: odoo

I'm having a field to store website link. I need to print that field in qweb and also to open a url link in new tab when click on it.

How can i do it?

Code:

```
<xpath expr="//div[@class='footer']" position="replace">
        <div class="footer">
        <hr style="width:100%;border:1px solid black;"/>
        <div style="border:1px solid black;width:100%;">
                        <img t-att-src="'/module/static/description/image.png'" />
        </div>
        <div style="border:1px solid black;width:100%;float:center;text-align:center;font-size:50px;">
                        <a t-attf-href="#{doc.company_id.website}">example.com</a>

        </div><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a t-attf-href="#{doc.company_id.website}"><span t-field="doc.company_id.website"/>
```

or

```
<a href="${doc.company_id.website}" target="_blank">${doc.company_id.website}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, but both the cases are not working in footer for me.

Comment: @Saks_here which odoo version you are using?

Comment: version 14 and thanks so much. I found out where the problem is. There might be a bug in wktmltopdf in my system.

Answer (score -1):

That's just pure HTML:

```xml
<a href="https://www.example.com/">example.com</a>
```

If you have a field value and your record in the context of rendering is `o` and the field name `url`, you can also use QWeb:

```xml
<a t-att-href="o.url" t-esc="o.url" />
```

Comment: This is not what i need sir. I need to print the field value in href link. For example: I'm having a field named "website" on form. I need to print its value in qweb. If someone click on it , it should open a link in new tab.

Comment: I added a QWeb solution.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work in qweb footer.

Comment: Can you please add the footer hint to your question?

Comment: I edited my question by adding code. Kindly help me to know where i need to made changes.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I rectified it.